# Uso de Grid, Windows Phone C# Silverlight?

Tags: windows-phone, xaml

Bom, estou tendo problemas ao desenvolver apps no Visual Studio, meu computador é 32 bits, logo não tem como eu testar os apps com emulador, e teste no meu próprio telefone, um Lumia com 4 polegadas.

No meu último projeto, que tinha tudo para ser um grande app, tive a frustação de ver ele não funcionar em aparelhos com outros tipos de rela, logo relacionei isso ao uso da tag "Grid", pois nele usei diversas assim como fazemos em html com as divs, para separar a tela em quadros e depois transformar esses quadros em tabelas, com linhas e colunas.

Minha pergunta não tem muito haver com código em geral mas sim com o uso dessa tag em geral, o uso excessivo dela pode sim comprometer o app? Existe tambem o StackPanel que seria um painel, porem não sei realmente para que cada um serve e como usar, alguém poderia me dar uma luz sobre isso? Pois o demais está legal sei usar, so essa questão que não deixam meus apps funcionarem, já perdi a esperança por isso.

Comment: Está desenvolvendo para `WP10`? Recomendo focar WP10 e aprender sobre `AdaptiveTrigger` para não se frustar novamente.

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo para Windows Phone 8.X já que a maioria dos smartphones estão com o 8.1, estou esperando um pouco para migrar o desenvolvimento para o 10. Bom, retirei as Grids e coloquei StackPanel amanha irei fazer um teste no celular da namorada kk que tem uma resolução diferente da minha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O grande benefício do uso do Grid é seu suporte para criação de linhas e colunas. Funciona de maneira semelhante a um Table em HTML.

Fiz um app que está publicado na windows Phone Store e usa o redimensinamento dinamico, ou seja, o Grid sempre fica com 100% da tela, independente da resolução do aparelho.

Um artigo muito bom que me ajudou na época que fiz o aplicativo, está na propria documentação da Microsoft e trata do layout de aplicações.

Para um Grid "auto-ajustavel", veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="1st row 1st column" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Text="3rd row 1st column" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Content="1st row 2nd column" FontSize="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Content="3rd row 2nd column" FontSize="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

**Resultado do código:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do artigo: [Layout for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/jj207042(v=vs.105).aspx)

Abraços.

Comment: Eu descobri que o erro não era as grids, e sim um método que estava usando para receber a resolução do aparelho (para personalizar o menu hambúrguer e animações), sei de uns sites bons com tutoriais em português e tenho um blog tambem ensinando, se quiser te passo.. Agora pude concluir meu segundo app na Windows Store :)

Comment: Pode passar sim. Conhecimento sempre é bom :)

Comment: O primeiro é eduardorizo.com.br aprendi bastante com ele e complementei colocando aqui nesse outro: lvilarinho.wordpress.com